# presentModalViewController not showing from separate UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with this method:

```
-(void)prepareToShowVault {

...

UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:passcodeViewController];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
        [passcodeViewController release];
        [passcodeNavigationController release];
}
```

When called from another method in this UIViewController, it works just fine. But when called from another UIViewController, this method fires but the code doesn't display a new modalViewController, presumably because the UIViewController with the above method isn't active. How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs it says

**modalViewController**

> The controller for the active modal view—that is, the view that is temporarily displayed on top of the view managed by the receiver. (read-only)

So I would guess that unless your view controller is the active one you will not see the modal view that it presents.

Therefore you need to either be in that view controller or add the method to the other view controller as well possibly using a category that you add to both.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you pushing a navigation controller? A navigation controller is already present. Don't create a navigation controller. I think you should simply be doing-

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeViewController animated:YES];
```

HTH,

Akshay